# Verificar URL da Imagem antes de atualizar State no React/Next

Tags: javascript, react, next.js

**A logica abaixo é em: React/Nextjs com styled-components.**

Olá, eu tenho um componente que "renderiza" o banner de um blog (**background-image**), a url vem de um **state** que já tem uma imagem padrão.

```
const [blogBanner, setBlogBanner] = useState('/images/imageBlogDefault.png')
```

Mas antes do componente receber esse state, o codigo faz uma verificação se aquele blog ja tem um banner definido pelo usuario. Se sim, então pega a url e atualiza o **state**.

```
if (props.blog.image) {
    setBlogBanner(`${hlp.BACKEND_HOST}/images/blogBanners/${props.blog.image}`)
}
```

> E no styled-components uso o **background-image: url(blogBanner)**.

**O problema** é que a requisição que pega os blogs retorna apenas a url do banner e não a imagem em si, então se por algum motivo a imagem for apagada do banco de dados sem remover a url dela no blog... quando for carregar esse blog o meu codigo vai "entender" que aquele blog "tem imagem" e vai atualizar o state com a nova url.

Então o que preciso é que alem de verificar se tem uma url (como ja faço), eu preciso verificar se aquela url retorna uma imagem antes de atualizar o state, mas não sei como fazer isso. Poderia ser até mesmo com css (styled-component) se fosse possivel.

Comment: Eu tentei fazer uma função que faz uma requisição get com a url da imagem e se o status retornado for 404 então nao atualiza o state, mas não funcionou. -->     async function teste(url) {
        const response = await fetch(url)
        console.log(response)
        if (response.status == 200) {
            setBlogBanner(/** Atualiza banner*/)
        }
    }

    if (props.portfolios.images[0]) {
        teste(bannerURL)
    }

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar criar um objeto de *Image* para verificar se é possível carregar a imagem.

A ideia é que você cria o objeto e usa os métodos *onload()* e *onerror()* para verificar se foi possível ou não carregar a imagem, caso tenha sido possível, você atualiza o *state* *blogBanner*, caso contrário mantém a imagem padrão (ou aplica algum outro tratamento adequado para sua aplicação).

Seu código poderia ser algo similar a isso:

```
if (props.blog.image) {
  // Pegando a URL para imagem
  const url = `${hlp.BACKEND_HOST}/images/blogBanners/${props.blog.image}`;
  // Criando um objeto Image
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = url;
  // Se foi possível carregar a imagem
  img.onload = () => {
    console.log("Essa imagem ainda existe no seu servidor");
    setBlogBanner(url);
  };
  // Caso não seja possível
  img.onerror = () => {
    console.log("A imagem não existe mais, continuar com a img padrão");
  };
};
```

Comment: Uma nota adicional: essa técnica pode ser usada para lazy loading também.

Comment: Tentei essa solução mas sempre que definir "new image()" em um componente, devolve o erro.

Unhandled Runtime Error

TypeError: _ref is undefined